# Do Chrome Apps support script.async = false?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, google-chrome-app

I am using the following to append scripts to the DOM and execute them in order:

```
function appendScript(url) {
    var elem = document.createElement('script');
    elem.src = url;
    elem.async = false;
    document.head.appendChild(elem);
}
```

See [HTML5 rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/).

They are loaded non-sequentially (good):

[image]

And they execute non-sequentially (bad), roughly smallest to largest, but varying. I have lots of JS errors because things are defined the order they were supposed to be.

This simple loader works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, and Safari.

But it doesn't work in a Chrome app.

Am I missing something?

---

My current workaround:

```
var script;
function appendScript(url) {
    var elem = document.createElement('script');
    elem.src = url;
    elem.async = false;
    if(script) {
        script.onload = function() {
            document.head.appendChild(elem);
            script = null;
        };
        script = elem;
    } else {
        document.head.appendChild(elem);
        script = elem;
    }
}
```

This waits until the script has loaded (and run) before starting to load the next.
The drawback is load time, since there is no (I/O) parallelism.

Comment: Using AMD modules would be one way to enforce proper dependency checking.

Comment: @Tomalak, okay...well how does AMD do it? (And does it work in a Chrome App?) Ultimately, they're using Javascript, so I should be able to replicate the same behavior.